# Can not predict on Front end streamlit with ktrain model, kindly provide suggestions about how to provide input for predict function

Tags: keras, regression, predict, streamlit, ktrain

***Can not predict on Front end streamlit with ktrain model, kindly provide suggestions about how to provide input for predict function.***

basically I would like to understand how to provide input for my saved ktrain regression model so that I can incorporate it to streamlit web app button.

I have tried putting array,list and dataframe as argument in .predict function still seems like missing something. as getting value error while hitting predict button.

```
import streamlit as st
from PIL import Image 
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow import keras
model = keras.models.load_model("predictor.h5")


st.write("This is an application to calculate Employee Mental Fatigue Score")
image = Image.open("IMG_2605.jpeg")
st.image(image, use_column_width=True)

WFH_Setup_Available = st.text_input("is work from home enabled for you?")
Designation =st.text_input("what is your designation?")
Average_hours_worked_per_day = st.text_input("how many hours you work on an average per day?")
Employee_satisfaction_score = st.text_input("Please enter your satisfaction score on scale of 10")
data = ['WFH_Setup_Available', 'Designation', 'Average_hours_worked_per_day' , 'Employee_satisfaction_score']


def mental_fatigue_score(WFH_Setup_Available, Designation, Average_hours_worked_per_day, Employee_satisfaction_score):
  prediction = model.predict([[WFH_Setup_Available, Designation, Average_hours_worked_per_day, Employee_satisfaction_score]])
  print(prediction)
  return prediction


if st.button("Predict"):
  result= mental_fatigue_score(WFH_Setup_Available, Designation, Average_hours_worked_per_day, Employee_satisfaction_score)
  st.success('The output is {}'.format(result))
```

[image]
**kindly suggest how to provide input to .predict function for streamlit web app.
I have trained predictor using ktrain regressors.**

Comment: I corrected what I used earlier, simply by putting st.text_input variables as arguments to my .predict as a list of strings but getting the same highlighted error.

guess there is very basic mistake while predicting from ktrain.

Comment: I didn't realize which model you're using.   If this is a tabular regression model and you're using Keras directly, the input has to be formatted in one of several different specific ways (e.g., generator, Numpy array, etc.): https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it by myself by saving ktrain model as

```
predictor.save('predictor')
predictor = ktrain.load_predictor('predictor')
```

when I save as predictor it creates a folder in which I have one **tf_mode.h5** & **tf_model.preproc**.

this was easier than what I expected it to be.

further for train input should be dataframe like below-

```
data = {'WFH_Setup_Available':WFH_Setup_Available,'Designation':Designation, 'Company_Type':Company_Type, 
        'Average_hours_worked_per_day': Average_hours_worked_per_day, 'Employee_satisfaction_score': Employee_satisfaction_score}

data = pd.DataFrame([data])
```